# VbScript make computer say something error

Tags: windows, vbscript, speech

I have this file that makes a computer say something. I want it to loop with a VbCancel function. I get this error. Code so far:

```
Do
    Dim Message, Speak
    Message=InputBox("Enter text","Speak")
    Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    MsgBox ("You entered: " & Speak)
    Speak.Speak Message
    If Len(Speak) = 0 Then
        MyMessageBox = MsgBox("Click Yes if you mean to Cancel." & vbCrLf & _
                       "If you mean to enter a zero length string, click No.", vbYesNo, "DO YOU MEAN TO CANCEL?")
            If MyMessageBox = vbYes Then
                MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
                Exit Sub
            End If
Loop
```

BTW the error is Invalid exit statement
I'm working on Windows 7

Comment: Your Dim should be outside the loop. Your first If has no End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Message, Speak

Do
    Message=InputBox("Enter text","Speak")
    Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    MsgBox ("You entered: " & Message)
    Speak.Speak Message
    If Len(Message) = 0 Then
        MyMessageBox = MsgBox("Click Yes if you mean to Cancel." & vbCrLf & _
                       "If you mean to enter a zero length string, click No.", vbYesNo, "DO YOU MEAN TO CANCEL?")
            If MyMessageBox = vbYes Then
                MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
                Exit Do
            End If
    End If
Loop
```

You had *several* issues here

1. `Exit Sub` is for subroutines. You were trying to exit a `Do` loop
2. `Speak` is an object. I dont know if it has a string property but it is not itself a string. Both `Len(Speak)` and `"You entered: " & Speak` has `Speak` changed to `Message`.
3. You were missing an `End If`
4. I moved the Dim statements out of the loop. No point recreating the object over and over again.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim Message, Speak

Do
    Message=InputBox("Enter text","Speak")
    Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    MsgBox ("You entered: " & Message)
    Speak.Speak Message
    If Len(Message) = 0 Then
        MyMessageBox = MsgBox("Click Yes if you mean to Cancel." & vbCrLf & _
                       "If you mean to enter a zero length string, click No.", vbYesNo, "DO YOU MEAN TO CANCEL?")
            If MyMessageBox = vbYes Then
                MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
                Exit Do
            End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: That's not the way to do it.